# Correlation / information between $X$ and $Z$ not explained through an intermediate variable $Y$

Tags: regression, correlation, information-theory

Let $X, Y, Z$ be r.v's. Suppose $X$ has some influence on $Y$ and $Z$, and $Y$ has some influence on $Z$. Can we quantify the influence $X$ has on $Z$, which is not due to the influence $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$?

Regress $Y = \beta_1 X + \alpha_1 + \epsilon_1$, then $Y_X = \beta_1 X + \alpha_1$ is the part of $Y$ explained by $X$. Next, regress $Z = \beta_2 Y + \alpha_2 + \epsilon_2$, expanding to get $Z = \beta_2 Y_X + (\beta_2\epsilon_1 + \alpha_2 + \epsilon_2)$.

Since the former term is the part of $Z$ explained by $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$, the latter term must be the part of $Z$ which isn't. Therefore we want $\text{Cor}(X, \beta_2\epsilon_1 + \alpha_2 + \epsilon_2) = \text{Cor}(X, \beta_2\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2)$.

What is the name of this type of correlation? (I am pretty sure it isn't just the partial correlation). Also what is the corresponding notion in information theory?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this would be quantified (and labeled as) the "direct effect" that X has on Z in a path (mediation) model that consists of two simultaneous regression equations:

Y = intercept_Y + aX + error_Y

Z = intercept_Z + bY + cX + error_Z

The direct effect of X on Z is given by the regression coefficient c (often referred to as c' in the statistical mediation literature). "Direct effect" here means that part of the total effect of X on Z that is not mediated by Y. The indirect (mediated) effect is given by the product ab. The total effect would be equal to the sum c + ab.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is my analysis incorrect? I think there are are issues with multicollinearity for this equation Z you listed. It would be helpful if you could sketch a derivation for this solution like in the post.

Comment: Tbh you haven't really answered the question - I'm looking to measure the strength of the relationship (with a correlation for example). This number c' doesn't do that, in the same way a regression coefficient doesn't measure **strength** of linear relationship.

Comment: A partial regression coefficient (such as c or c') is a measure of strength of the linear relationship. It takes into account collinearity (correlation between Y and X).

Comment: A derivation of direct vs. indirect effects would look like this: Insert what you have for Y in the first equation into the second equation. Then you can see that Z = intercept_Z + bInterceptY + abX + berror_Y + cX + error_Z. So Z depends on X both directly (path c) and indirectly (product ab).

Comment: I guess I don't understand how you obtained Z=β2YX+(β2ϵ1+α2+ϵ2).
Can you explain?

Comment: One way to get what I believe you may be looking for in terms of a squared correlation type metric is by means of the squared semi-partial correlation between Z and X (thereby partialling Y from X). This squared semi-partial correlation gives you the R-square change (increase) when X is added to the model for Z (i.e., the proportion of variance that X accounts for in Z above and beyond what can be explained in Z by Y alone).

Comment: There was a typo in the first expression for $Z$. Ive corrected that now.

Comment: I am trying to capture "the proportion of variance that X accounts for in Z above and beyond what can be explained in Z by X through influence on Y then in turn Z" rather than "the proportion of variance that X accounts for in Z above and beyond what can be explained in Z by Y alone".